# Get value by key from class inheriting form HashSet/Dictionary

Tags: c#

I have a code converted from Java to C# wherein I have a class which inherits a hashtable class. I am able access methods like Add(), CopyTo() etc directly. However I am not able to get the value by key from inside the subclass.

How to get value of indexed property from inside class?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simply

```
this[key]
```

........

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the indexer, e.g. `dictionary[key]`. If you're inside the class, use `this[key]`.

Comment: ya but that is when we initialize a hashatable.. but im inheriting it... i am able to access properties like Count etc.. But do not know how to get value from key

Comment: That *is* how you get the value from the key.

Comment: Yup, as crashmstr and Jonathan Allen said, you just need to use `this[key]`.